# How to match two arrary index in android

Tags: android, arraylist, android-videoview

I have a doubt in my app...

I have an image **arraylist** and videos **arraylist**. I've displayed the images in list.

Now what I need is - On **onItemClick** of image list, I need to play the matched video of respective image. How do I implement this?

Also, how to match the two array list? Is there any possibility? 
Would appreciate help. Thanks!

code..

```
 Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
 Array = bundle.getStringArrayList("string-array");
 Link = bundle.getStringArrayList("link-array");
 GridViewConfig.addImageUrls();
 girGridView=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1_bir);
 girGridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
 girGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){      
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,long arg3) {
         startActivity(new Intent(
             Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
             Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=PASSD2OcU0c")
         ));
     }
```

Comment: mWebView.loadUrl(Link.get(position));. I am not sure i understand your question completely. Try this. in on item click.

Comment: Why don't you use a HashMap ?

Comment: don't play your video in webview , try to play in youtube player ,if you are playing only youtube videos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think  use hashmap is better,the key is you image and the value is you video url

Comment: in your onItemClick function,you can get the image Tag, you can get the video url from the hashmap with image tag

Comment: if you don't know how to get image Tag attribute,you'd search on google with 'girGridView.setOnItemClickListener'

Comment: i got the image link in onItemClick by using get(position) then what i should do

Comment: @OneManArmy you have gridview with a image. when you click on the image you should play a corresponding video? Does this mWebView.loadUrl(Link.get(position));. not work in on item click?

Comment: @minjie yes when i click on the image i should play corresponding video... then how can i implement this? Any possible..